# Thunderbird Exchange and Gmail Calendar Merge

Tags: thunderbird, gmail

**I have the following scenario:**
 
     - An Exchange Corporate Account configured on thunderbird
 
     - A Google Account (calendar configured on thunderbird)
 
     - Ubuntu 12.04
 
     - Thunderbird
 
 
 

 **The problem:**
 
     - I have a Gmail account to sync with my mobile phone, in the past, when I used to have <del>windows</del> on my corporate laptop, I used to have a useful application called "Google calendar Sync" that synchronizes (merges) the outlook calendar with Google calendar. I'd like to have something like this on my Linux, as synchronizing (merging) it I can see all my meetings on my mobile.



**The workaround:**
 
   - Meanwhile I manually duplicate all corporate meetings to my google account for it to synchronize with the mobile, but it is so annoying, I'd like this to be periodically and automatically made, as I had on "Google Calendar Sync".

 
  Can someone help me?

 
  Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Google sync has been abandoned. Use SyncEvolution (works on evolution-data-server) to sync between exchange calendar & Google-Calendar.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution.

Answer (score 2):

there are a number of addons on thunderbird which sycs google tasks, calendar and google contacts without breaking a sweat.the addons are 1. provider for googe calendar 2. google task sync 3. zindus . all three are two way sync addons.

Comment: OK
These 3 addons helps me to manage my gmail account, but doesn't solve my problem. I was already using them.
The problem is that I'd like to automatically copy every meeting from my Corporate Exchange Account Calendar to my Gmail Account Calendar, this is the point.

Comment: Ok. I get it. Unfortunately, this feature from Google is being removed. Please see the link http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2716936